# Add /demo/ slug with rewrite rule

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add extra parameters after permalink?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/add-extra-parameters-after-permalink)

I need to add a slug to every post.

**Current permalinks**

http://www.my-domain.com/2012/01/01/my-post-title/ or
http://www.my-domain.com/my-post-title/

**Rewritten permalinks**

http://www.my-domain.com/2012/01/01/my-post-title/demo/ or
http://www.my-domain.com/my-post-title/demo/

**Additional information**

- My demo-page should not return a 404-page.
- I should be able to get the current ID of the post "my-post-title" from my demo-page.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api).

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60173/rewrite-rule-for-multilingual-website-like-qtranslate