# How to create custom URLs for Custom Post Type sub sections?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

Not sure how to ask this, because I'm not exactly sure what I'm asking.

I'm looking to use custom URLs (using rewrite rules maybe?) to create 'tabs' for a Custom Post Type. In the past I've used things like a GET session variable to determine what tab the user is on, or JavaScript. I would really prefer to keep it on it's own logical page with a URL to reflect that.

A very basic look of the tabs would be:

`HOME | UPDATES | CONTRIBUTORS | WALL`

For example if we're on the CPT of Charity's sub page of Updates: `http://siteroot/charity/updates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an end point for the permalinks. [See example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51450/73).

Then you can even be more granular and use `updates/2012`, `updates/2013` and so on.

Recommended reading:

- [Codex: `add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)
- [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to the WordPress Rewrite API](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/)

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly what I was trying to communicate! I am reading through the examples and codex documentation now - this is incredibly helpful!