# Choose template depending on URL

Tags: permalinks, templates

I have the following basic page setup:

- xxx.net/ -> static homepage
- xxx.net/blog/ -> blog page with loop showing all posts
- xxx.net/gallery/ -> gallery page with loop only showing posts that are categorized as "gallery"
- xxx.net/extra/ -> another page with loop only showing posts that are categorized as "extra"

The two special categories "gallery" and "extra" are used to filter certain posts and display them in a different way:

On `/gallery`, only posts of category "gallery" are shown (actually there custom excerpts rather than their standard content); the equivalent holds true for "extra".

So far that's all clear to me, however depending on whether a post is shown as part of the blog loop or the other loops, different post templates are used: if a post is called via `xxx.net/gallery/post-name`, the gallery template is used, if called via `xxx.net/blog/post-name`, the standard template is used.

How can I do this? I somehow think the answer is simple but I just don't see it right now!
Would it make sense to use a new, custom taxonomy rather than categories to distinguish the "special" posts? The main question regarding permalinks remains the same however.

Addition:

I guess I could create a `single.php` with the following switcher:

```
if ( URL INCLUDES /GALLERY/ ) {include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-gallery.php');}
else if ( URL INCLUDES /EXTRA/ ) { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-extra.php');}
else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php'); }
```

However I think a rewrite rule or similar would be the better approach.
What is your take on the topic?

Second Addition:

To further explain why I would like this functionality:
Think of a trip report. It contains some text (the actual trip report) plus a collection of photos (the trip gallery). Instead of seperating the two things by creating two different posts, I would like to create only one post with the text as content and the photos as attachments.

Then I would also like to allow the visitor to

a) read the post as a standard blog entry with standard output without the photos by calling `.../blog/post-name`

b) view the post as a photo album (e.g. thumbnail page) by calling `.../gallery/post-name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One post cannot (and should not) have two single post URLs. All you can change is the archive view, the list of posts.

If `/gallery/` and `/extra/` are post of the post type `page`, use a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) for those.

### Update

[Create two endpoints](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51450/73) `gallery` and `extra` for the root (`EP_ROOT`) ([another example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54612/73)). The callback function for those endpoints the has two options:

1. If the endpoint variable value is `TRUE` (`/gallery/` was called without a post name), render an archive listing.
2. If there is a string value, use `get_page_by_path()` and fetch the post object. Render it.

Example for `get_page_by_path()`:

```
$post = get_page_by_path( 
    get_query_var( 'gallery' ), 
    OBJECT, 
    'post' 
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Please check my addition to the original question for the reasoning behind this question.

Comment: ... maybe you have a bette ridea how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Actually, can I not (in theory) use URL rewrite rules to redirect as many URLs as I want to the same page (in this case the same post)?

Comment: @Dreamingof8a See my update.