# How to show one page with two different templates

Tags: url-rewriting, page-template

I have a page template that I want to be able to show in two different modes: a regular mode and a bare-bones mode, where there is no header, footer, sidebar, etc.  My hope is that I can get this done using a parent-child url, like so:

Normal view: http://sample.com/mypage/

Barebones view: http://sample.com/mypage/clean/

I assume I will need to edit header.php as well as footer.php to check whether or not they should show up, but how do I figure out the parent-child relationship, or is there an easier way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add an endpoint to your post permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/add-extra-parameters-after-permalink/51450#51450), name it `clean`.

In your callback for `template_redirect` use a special `header.php` or none at all. Do not forget to call `exit;`; otherwise WordPress will load the default template files later.