# Preserving $_GET parameter while using custom Rewrite Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

This [third party add-on plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-update-post/) for Gravity Forms allows you to edit existing posts via the front end when you embed a form in your chosen template.

All you need to do is append the GET variable/parameter `?gform_post_id=1` to the end of your URL which contains the current form and it will pre-populate your form with existing post data (from post meta fields, etc) and then update the post when you re-submit it.

This works only when using a get style parameter attached to your URL in the form of `?gform_post_id=1`... where `1` is the post ID in this example.

I don't want ugly URLs, I want pretty URLs, so  I'm using the following re-write rules to tidy up my permalinks;

```
function gform_rewrite(){

    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_tag('%gform_post_id%','([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^user/account/edit/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=183&gform_post_id=$matches[1]','top'
     );
}
```

Which takes this,

```
/index.php?page_id=100&gform_post_id=1
```

...and allows for this instead,

```
/user/account/edit/1
```

My `query_vars` are set as you can see in a `var_dump`

```
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(56) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    int(100)
    ["gform_post_id"]=>
    string(3) "1"
    //....etc
```

Of course though with pretty permalinks on, the `$_GET` variable no longer holds my `gform_post_id` parameter which means that although the following shows the correct destination as per the rewrite rule above,

```
/user/account/edit/1
```

...it does not pre-populate my form with post data as it does when accessing the same page directly via,

```
/index.php?page_id=100&gform_post_id=1
```

Any thoughts on ways around this?

### Notes:

The [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-update-post/) as linked in my opening declares the following line;

```
$this->get_post_object($_REQUEST[$this->options['request_id']]);
```

...to extract data out of of the $_REQUEST variable;

The option `request_id` is mapped to `gform_post_id` which should be set as the `$_GET` variable parameter.

```
  public $options = array(
    'request_id' => 'gform_post_id' // here we are...
    ,'post_status' => 'default'
    ,'capabilities' => array(
      'update' => 'default' 
      ,'delete' => 'disable' 
    )
    ,'entries' => true
  );
```

I have tried hooking onto the `request` filter and setting the `$_GET` variable myself but to no avail. I could be hooking to late in the piece but as it stands I'm a little unsure of how to tackle this problem without directly modifying the plugin itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to ultimately unhook the construct function on init within the plugin and then re-add the plugin construct function on the `wp` hook.

```
 global $gform_update_post;
 remove_action( 'init', array($gform_update_post, 'init'), 100 );
 add_action( 'wp', array($gform_update_post, 'init'), 100 );
```

This now means that I can access:

```
/user/account/edit/1
```

...successfully with my form pre-populating data pertaining to the post ID in this case `1`.

However when re-submitting this form it creates a new post ID instead of updating the original post ID `1` as shown in the URL.

Therefore in my situation I did this;

```
 global $gform_update_post;
 add_action( 'wp', array($gform_update_post, 'init'), 100 );
```

...instead of removing the original construct action within the plugin, I left it in place, and instead re-declared the construct action on the `wp` hook which ensured all of the necessary Gravity Form hooks are firing in the right place to allow the form to update the same post ID in which I am editing (shown in URL).

Beyond that I couldn't be bothered trying to figure out what specifically within the plugin was causing this update vs create new post ID quirk.

For anyone else trying this with the Gravity Forms add-on as listed in my OP you still need to set your `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` variable on the `request` action hook, like so:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'alter_the_query', 1 );

function alter_the_query( $request ) {
   $_REQUEST['gform_post_id'] =  $request['gform_post_id'];
       return $request;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an API for exactly your use case: endpoints. [Register an endpoint for `EP_PERMALINK`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51450/73) and when it is set display your form.