# Extend page routing with custom parameters

Tags: routing

In WordPress there is defined a simple routing

```
/%postname%/
```

So when I access `/projects/` it loads me `Projects` page which has specified custom `template_projects.php` template.

Is it possible to extend routing but only for this template ?

Let's say I want to extend routing to handle project id, so it should be:

```
/%postname%/%project-id%/
```

But other pages will work with base route.

Comment: Have you tried [endpoints](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51450/73)?

Comment: @toscho endpoints don't suit in this case...

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to register custom post type for your projects. You can do it by using [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_post_type) function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_register_post_type' );
function wpse8170_register_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'wpse8170-projects', array(
        'label'   => 'Projects',
        'public'  => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'project' ),
    ) );
}
```

> Don't forget to [flush rewrite rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

After you register your custom post type, your projects will have `/project/%wpse8170-projects%` (`%wpse8170-project%` will be replaced by project slug) permalink structure and you will be able to use `single-wpse8170-projects.php` template for your projects.

Comment: Explain me please, why there is `wpse8170` keyword ?

Comment: I have already did it, but I want to 'consume' projects in specified Page. So I have to fetch project in `/projects/project-slug` but `projects` post has to be available too.

Comment: @hsz `wpse8170` is unique prefix which prevents collision issues. You can pick up your own unique prefix and use it in your development.

Comment: @hsz use `archive-wpse8170-projects.php` template to render archive page for project posts. In this template, fetch `projects` post/page and render it's content instead of rendering projects list.