# Rewrite Endpoints and CPTs - How to use in a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm working on rewrite rules for a plugin that uses a URL endpoint, `/modifier`, to create a `query_var` `&modifier=1` to signify it should do something else.

The rewrite deals with URLs where `/modifier` is appended to the end of a URL for a post, page, or custom post type.

It seems like [adding a rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) would be ideal, but according to the Wordpress [rewrite endpoints API](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) the incoming URL would need to end with a value, like `/modifier/1` in order to rewrite automatically to `&modifier=1` via the endpoint API. If there's no value after the endpoint, it resolves to `&modifier=` and has no value when checking if it `isset`.

So I'm still doing it the long way, via `generate_rewrite_rules`. The rewrite for posts and pages works fine - I could include it but maybe it's not relevant.

The rewrite for custom post types, added at the top, also works when a post type is explicitly hardcoded.

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite');
function my_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
    // rewrite rules for custom post type "specific-type"
    $cpt_rules = array(
        'specific-type-slug/([^/]+)/modifier' => 'index.php?specific-type='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) .'&modifier=1'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $cpt_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

The problem is making a loop for all custom post types. `get_post_types()` is only available after `init`. This rewrite is filtering `generate_rewrite_rules`, several steps earlier.

So here's the loop I've tried. It obviously doesn't work, the post types aren't set up yet.

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite');
function my_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
  global $wp_post_types;
  $types = get_post_types( array( '_builtin' => false ) );
  // get the registered data about each post type with get_post_type_object
  foreach( $types as $type ) {
    $cpt_rules = '';
    $typeobj = get_post_type_object( $type );

    if( isset( $typeobj->rewrite->slug ) ) {
        $slug = $typeobj->rewrite->slug;
        $cpt_rules = array(
            $slug.'/([^/]+)/modifier' => 'index.php?'.$type.'='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) .'&modifier=1'
        );
        $wp_rewrite->rules = $cpt_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    }
  }
}
```

Something tells me using a plugin class might be the way to solve this, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Update: it is certainly a heck of a lot easier to just change the URL to `modifier/1` and use the endpoint API, I can confirm this works. Still I'm curious if there's a way to use the query_var `modifier` even if it is not followed by a value in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

*Apologies if this seemed too obvious to answer, i'm just getting my head around htaccess rewrites in wordpress.*

The most elegant way to parse the modifier through the URL like this seems to be to add a rewrite endpoint and just check for it in the URL later, if you don't want to pass a value.

The beauty is there's no need for any other rewrite rules, as long as you're just checking for this endpoint.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wp_modifier_endpoint' );
function wp_modifier_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'modifier', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
```

In the function creating the `/modifier` links, there's also no need to add a value after `/modifier/value` either, unless you need a value. My previous technique checked if the endpoint (as query_var) isset, but you can just check for the endpoint string within the URL with the php `strrpos` function.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$endpoint = substr( $url, 9 ); /* number of chars in string "/modifier" */
if( false !== strpos( $endpoint, '/modifier' ) ) {
    /* do something; */
}
```

**Update: per Milo's comment below, it is preferable to check if `modifier` is an `array_key` of `query_vars`** - this seems more foolproof and easily extensible, in case you want to check for multiple keys.

```
global $wp_query;
if( array_key_exists( 'modifier' , $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
    /* do your thing; */
}
```

Comment: [see this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51449/4771) for another way of detecting the presence of an endpoint in a request.

Comment: Thanks Milo. Unfortunately `if array_key_exists( 'modifier', $wp_query->query_vars )` didn't work for me when I just tried it in the checking function. I was getting hopeful! For sure, "modifier" has been added to public_query_vars within the plugin earlier.

Comment: if it's within a function you need to [globalize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) `$wp_query` before you can access it: `global $wp_query;`

Comment: hahaa!!! indeed you do. oh, man. thanks. it works now, and i think this is preferable to looking in the string