# Stuck with WordPress Multisite Custom signup page without .htaccess modification

Tags: multisite, signup, wp-signup

Yes, stuck with creating a custom signup page for [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

It's a well revised question, and many of us is seeking the answer. May be somebody got one, but still, I can't find any solid, holistic one for the issue. I'm trying to find a non `.htaccess` way - a PHP' or a WordPress' way.

#### Step 1:

I studied the most obvious article found in this quest:

- [Using a Custom wp-signup Page With WordPress MU](https://www.chriswiegman.com/2010/02/using-a-custom-wp-signup-page-with-wordpress-mu/) - *Chris Wiegman*

Okay, now I've copied all the code of `/wp-signup.php` to a file in my theme named `signup.php`, make it a page template and called the page with the URL `http://example.com/signup`.

I made changes to the required places. Like instead of `get_header( 'wp-signup' );` I used my custom one from my theme `get_header('null');`. That one (`header-null.php`) is pretty bare-bone in design and architecture from the default `header.php` file of my theme.

> *Alas! There is no `header-wp-signup.php` in anywhere of WordPress*

Similarly I replaced `get_footer( 'wp-signup' );` with:

```
    ?> <!-- /ending of php tag -->
    </div> <!-- /.container .site-area .not-logged-in-page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Step 2:

@toscho helped me solving two issues of recalling files that are already loaded. So, instead of showing absolute paths, I simply commented out the lines:

```
//require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

and

```
//require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Now I've a nice, working file for newly modified sign-up page. I need to drive the traffic from `/wp-signup.php` to here, not using `.htaccess`.

#### Step 3:

I found this WordPress.org Support thread very helpful:

- [individual MU Registration Page possible?](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/individual-mu-registration-page-possible?replies=7#post-1711143) - *David Sader*

Now I made a "mu-plugin" making a file in: `wp-content/mu-plugins/sign-up-location.php`. There I used two functions:

```
/**
 * Changing the Registration page URL.
 * 
 * @return string The URL of the new page.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function project_signup_page() {
    $page =  network_site_url() .'signup/';
    return $page;
}
add_filter( 'wp_signup_location', 'project_signup_page' );


/**
 * Redirect from default signup page to custom page.
 * 
 * @return void
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function project_redirect_from_default_signup() {
    if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-signup.php')) {
        wp_redirect(network_site_url() .'signup/');
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'project_redirect_from_default_signup' );
```

The first one is changing the registration URL to my custom path. And the second one is my desired one, driving traffic from `/wp-signup.php` to `/signup` without `.htaccess`.

> **Note:** Instead of creating MU Plugin, you can get the same affect using a regular plugin now.

#### Step 4 (furnishing steps):

As per @toscho's suggestion I replaced the page template thing with a `Rewrite Endpoint`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Rewrite endpoint : /register.
 *
 * @return void
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function project_registration_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'register', EP_ROOT );
    if( get_option("EDIT_REWRITE_RULE") != 1 ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        update_option( "EDIT_REWRITE_RULE", 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'project_registration_endpoint' );

/**
 * Custom Template for Registration.
 *
 * @param  string $template Template to be loaded.
 * @return string           Our custom template to show up.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function project_custom_templates( $template ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        if( get_query_var('register') || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-signup.php') ) {
            $template = get_template_directory() .'/signup.php';
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'project_custom_templates' );

/**
 * Return a value for '/register'
 * Make sure that 'get_query_var( 'register' )' will not return just an empty string if it is set.
 *
 * @link   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51450/22728
 * @link   https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/
 *
 * @param  array $vars  Query variables.
 * @return array        Modified query variables.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function project_set_epex_var( $vars ) {
    isset( $vars['register'] ) and $vars['register'] = true;
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'project_set_epex_var' );
```

**Modified:** And at that point, I changed the slug `/signup` to `/register` to resolve any possible conflict, that can happen. I changed the mu-plugin's strings accordingly. And make the page template retired.

> **Everything is working fine**, and I got my desired thing :) ... except...

the success or error messages...
***all the success or error messages are gone*** with `wp_redirect()`. :o

I checked my file, yes, the `show_user_form()` is there with `$errors` parameter, everything is fine, except the error or success messages.

How can I display the success and/or error messages in my custom page signup page?

### In Bengali

I explained the whole thing in details with all the sources in Bengali, in my [blog post](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/make-custom-signup-page-wordpress-multisite/) - I'm afraid, automatic translation to Bengali is till not that good.

Comment: well done on getting to this point by the way... looks like a hack of a journey...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `signup.php` file, try changing the form `action` from `wp-signup.php` to `signup.php`... this way the form data is not passed through the redirect but rather directly back to the same file and this should preserve the `$errors` from the form posting.

Comment: hahaha! I overlook that tiny part... thank you @majick. thanks a lot. Hope this journey will solve the age-old mystery (*a what?*)... hahaha!!

Comment: glad i could help, it's always the little things eh? looks like your perserverence has paid off tho. :-)

Comment: My perseverance! :o It's my mentors. Thanks @toscho for taking me this far.