# Creating custom permalink structure for languages

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, multi-language

I've written a simple multi-language system, whereby clicking on a flag icon sets a one year cookie containing a two letter language code (e.g. nl, de, etc).

I hook into the `wp` action to read the cookie value, then use the `the_title` and `the_content` filters to show the correct language (the different languages are entered via metaboxes on the page/post edit screen).

This all works great except I'd also like to have permalinks for each language version whereby the two letter language code is between the domain name and the usual permalink structure. I'm using the `%postname%` permalink structure, so all the following would be valid:

```
http://example.com/nl/about-us
http://example.com/de
http://example.com/fr/2012/03
http://example.com/es/this-is-a-post-title
```

If the current language is English, then no two letter code should be used (it will just be the normal permalink).

So far I have used the `query_vars` filter to add a query var called `lang`, but that's sa far a I've got, I'm unsure what the next steps are. Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92394/6332

Comment: thanks @l2aelba, that answer is close enough to what i need with some minor changes.

Comment: Do you have subdomains for this or just a single website

Comment: just a single website

Answer (score 1):

Your question is complicated enough to answer by myself, but I would suggest you to install [`qTranslate`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) plugin. As the plugin's description says:

> Choose one of 3 Modes to make your URLs pretty and SEO-friendly. - The
>   everywhere compatible ?lang=en, simple and beautiful /en/foo/ or nice
>   and neat en.yoursite.com

So you can try to inspect the plugin's code and see how they do it, or just use it at all.

Comment: thanks for the link, i'll take a look to see if i can deconstruct the code.

Answer (score -1):

This is the filter I'm using:

```
function em_wpml_dbem_taxonomy_category_slug($option){
$lang = get_bloginfo('language');

if( $lang === 'es-ES' ){
    $option = 'eventos/categorias';
} else {
    $option = 'events/categories';
}
return $option;
}
add_filter('pre_option_dbem_taxonomy_category_slug', 'em_wpml_dbem_taxonomy_category_slug');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer - thanks.