# Add rewrite rule to call front-page.php?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, frontpage

I am trying to create a multilanguage website. And I have set my home page to a **static page** in my WP admin area.

This **home page ID is 2** and it calls `front-page.php` template when I am on the home page at this address, for example, `http://examplesite.com/`

So for a french version, I have added a new rewrite rule so I have this url, `http://examplesite.com/fr/`, and its call the same home page which is ID 2.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^fr/?$',
    'index.php?&p=2&lang=fr',
    'top'
)
```

But why it calls `index.php` template instead but **not** `front-page.php`?

How can I make `http://examplesite.com/fr/` to call `front-page.php`?

Comment: Because that's how WordPress handles requests made to your WordPress site. The `index.php` file would eventually load your `front-page.php` file, if the request was your site's home/front page - or the static Page in your case.

Comment: @SallyCJ it does not load `front-page.php` just as I explained above already.

Comment: If that rewrite rule works on its own, you've got something non-standard happening, as a default WordPress install would redirect that request to the root URL. If you disabled canonical redirect to prevent that, it would show the `front-page.php` template. You've got a theme or plugin that is somehow changing some fundamental parts of the query/template process, first step is to figure out if it's your theme or what plugin is doing this.

Comment: Yes I understand about that @laukok. I was referring to the "*why* `index.php`" as in the rewrite rule there. Try changing the `?&p=2` to `?page_id=2`?

Comment: @Milo I tested that rewrite rule to the WP default theme `twentyseventeen`. It gets even worst. It does not call `index.php` at all. WP somehow is forcing `http://examplesite.com/fr/` to redirect to `http://examplesite.com/`

Comment: @SallyCJ `?page_id=2` is  forcing `http://examplesite.com/fr/` to redirect to `http://examplesite.com/`.

Comment: In that case, you need to cancel redirect canonical when your rewrite rule matches the current request.

Comment: @SallyCJ how do I `cancel redirect canonical`?

Comment: @SallyCJ `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` and it now works with `page_id=2`. But why `page_id=2` not `p=2`?

Comment: @laukok Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I pointed in my comment, in the rewrite rule there, change `?&p=2` to `?page_id=2`. Because `p` is used for querying a Post (i.e. post of the `post` type). So for Pages (i.e. post of the `page` type), use `page_id`.

To prevent `http://examplesite.com/fr/` from being redirected to `http://examplesite.com/`, you can cancel (the) canonical redirect, like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
    }
}, 0 );
```

Comment: You're very welcome. :)